# Non-English Characters Not Allowed in PayPal Express Checkout Page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

My product names contain non-English characters like ç, ş, ı, ğ so I get the following error:

**Error Message:**

> transactions[0].item_list.items[1].name","issue":"Must contain only
> these characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, punctuation(.,#-'), and embedded
> spaces

**PayPal Api Method:**

https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

How can I show non-english characters in PayPal Express Checkout Page?

[image]

POST data that I sent to API

```
{"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"redirect_urls":{"return_url":"http:\/\/payment.shopioglobal.mil\/pay_pal\/success","cancel_url":"http:\/\/payment.shopioglobal.mil\/pay_pal\/fail"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":200,"details":{"shipping":0,"tax":0,"subtotal":200}},"item_list":{"items":[{"name":"Zebra","currency":"USD","quantity":1,"price":100},{"name":"K\u0131r\u0131k \u015eerafettin \u00d6zg\u00fcro\u011flu Hayvanat Bah\u00e7esi","currency":"USD","quantity":1,"price":100}]},"description":"Shopio Global"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rest API** doesn't support non US countries. So I solved this problem by using a **Classic API**

Comment: Hello Farid. My i ask a question due to this topic similar to mine.
I am developing a site with paypal.
Any idea how to make paypal accept on the address German characters like 'ö,ä,ü'?.
My Error is on 400 on checkout.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a language during the OAuth portion of your initial calls?
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers